# Cant allocate memory to Minecraft more than 3GB

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I know this question is probably a bit off-topic but i can't allocate more than 3GB to Minecraft(TLauncher, yeah i admit that i crack the game)

My Linux mint rig have total of 8GB ram and i wanted to **burn** my ram by allocating a lot of memory to Minecraft

Comment: Do you have a 64 bit OS and 64 big java installed?

Comment: Yes. It is an off topic question and will be closed. You should delete this and ask such questions on https://superuser.com/ instead.

Comment: @AidenGrossman yes my PC is all 64 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*click on the links to view images if needed*

**Newest TLauncher:**

[Click on the gear button, then select 'settings'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7Zlj.png)

[A settings menu pops up, and you can allocate RAM to Minecraft at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JKcm.png)

That's a way to allocate RAM to Minecraft. **Don't forget to click "save"**

[If Minecraft doesn't work / Won't start, try removing your JVM arguments.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPgZl.png)

**Old TLauncher:**

[Click on the three lines, then select 'preferences'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpRXg.jpg)

[A settings menu pops up, and you can allocate RAM to Minecraft at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXKF2.jpg)

[If Minecraft doesn't work / Won't start, try removing your JVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqKlz.jpg)

If nothing above worked, try removing your `/.minecraft/` directory.

*Using a non-official launcher doesn't mean your cracking the game, with most non-official launchers you can login to your official MC account.*

Comment: I mean about 3GB isnt enough to satisfy me. I really wanted to see Minecraft use up my ram

Comment: Are you trying to allocate more then 3GB RAM to Minecraft? You just need to change the value of how much RAM is given to Minecraft. Here is a [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/jaqvfm) of me starting Minecraft with 4GB allocated.